# Effect of (possibly missing) grounds in power amp output circuit

Tags: pcb, schematics, grounding, power-amplifier, hacking

***NOTE:** It turns out, the ground connections I wonder about below actually are connected (thanks Sim Son in comments),  although I still cannot see *how* they could be connected ([additional closeups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trgDS.jpg)). The reason I initially concluded they weren't connected was a combination of being unable to see connections on the PCB (still can't) along with, as it turns out, a broken probe on the meter I was using for continuity checks. So the main premise of this question *appears* to be incorrect; although the questions about the effect of said ground still stand.*

---

I am looking at the audio amplifier section from a mainboard scavanged from an LCD TV ([Sony BU Board, P/N 1-876-561-13](https://www.google.com/search?q=sony%201-876-561-13&tbm=isch), TV appears to be a KDL-40V4150). The amp circuit is built around a [TI TPA3100D2PHPR](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tpa3100d2.pdf?ts=1640811041562) chip (20W stereo class-D amp). The PCB appears to be a 2-layer board.<sup>†</sup>

I have been studying it, as I made a project out of cutting this section out of the mainboard and using it as a standalone amp (mostly worked). However, while closely examining it I noticed what *appears* to be an unexpectedly absent ground connection in the output section, and I'm not sure what to make of it.

### Schematics

Here is part of the schematic from [the TV's service manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1117364/Sony-Kdl-40v4150.html?page=43#manual) and the corresponding part of the example circuit in the chip's datasheet (click for high res). The only difference that might be relevant (?) is the Sony circuit doesn't have the 1nF + 20Ω decoupling bits off the outputs before the inductors. I've highlighted the suspicious ground connections in blue:

| Service Manual (Sony) | Datasheet (TI) |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Notes:

- Sony uses this board (or slight variants of it) in a bunch of TVs. I'm confident this is the correct service manual as I found the model # of the TV printed on the chassis.
- I assume that Sony uses this amp circuit in other products as well, since it is relatively self contained and I see lots of unused pads that I assume are for parts in other variants.

### PCB

That's all fine, but the reason for my question is **the PCB appears to not include the ground connections highlighted above**.

I manually followed all the ground traces on the PCB. Descriptions are with the images below (click to enlarge), the general components of interest are the capacitors after each inductor (C2096 thru C2099):

| Description | Back | Front |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TI chip in center. | [image] | [image] |
| Ground trace is green. Caps and the traces between them are purple. | [image] | [image] |
| Back image also shows front traces. Front image is service diagram instead of photo. | [image] | [image] |

The confusing bit is here:

[image]

The grounds are green and the caps and traces between them are purple. Unless I'm missing something, there is no connection on the PCB between the purple and the green. This would mean that the connections that I highlighted in the schematics aren't present.

### Question

So that was a lot of pictures but my question is:

Why might those connections be missing? Is it some other common configuration for a class-D amp's output that I don't know about? Is it related to the lack of decoupling capacitors at the chip's outputs before the coils?

Also, how does that ground affect the amp's behavior?

Basically: What's going on here?

Note: The outputs of this circuit go to two places: directly to the TV's internal speakers, and also to some other amp that drives the line-out jacks. There's some resistors and capacitors there too, not sure if they're relevant, but [here is that part of the circuit.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NKZDP.png)

---

<sup>†</sup> There is strong evidence that the PCB is only 2 layers:

1. I cut this from the main board with a bandsaw and only saw two layers on that border.
2. I am able to account for every connection on the schematic with the visible PCB traces *except* for this ground (I checked *carefully*, every component, in the amp section as well as the main audio processor and aux amp).
3. The service manual's PCB layouts ([page 54](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1117364/Sony-Kdl-40v4150.html?page=54#manual)) show two layers only, and have no indications of blind vias or traces.
4. It would be trivial to route those to the ground trace. The purple and green areas (from my images) are directly adjacent on the front side of the board.

So under the assumption that cost reduction is important, it seems to me like it would be strange for the PCB to have another layer just for a few connections that could just as easily be made on the existing layers.

Comment: Following copper traces can be tricky, did you check for continuity between the suspicious points to be sure they really aren't connected?

Comment: Any questions Jason?

Comment: @SimSon I swear I did. I just did again to double check and... they *are* connected to ground. And I absolutely can't see how. [I took some more closeups](https://imgur.com/a/2HrggyH). Also this completely changes the question.... I'm 100% baffled how they are connected.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I have so many questions, heh....

Comment: @SimSon Oh my; I just now figured out why my continuity tests failed the first time... looks like one of the probes on my meter has a broken internal connection, making it sensitive to the angle it's held at... bad combo when considered with the seemingly invisible connection that's actually on the board. Argh. Time for video games and cats, I'll come back to this tomorrow. I'm fried.

Comment: Fwiw, I figure out the TV model and was able to find the correct service manual. No relevant differences. I've updated the links and images though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for a well presented question.

Page 19 of the referenced TI datasheet suggests the output filtering is optional. Depending on the target market and the exact application, Sony have determined it was not necessary. They may have put a common mode choke on the speaker wires. TVs are a high volume product and heavily cost engineered to specific markets. If they can eliminate a component, they will.

The filtering is for EMC purposes and does not affect the normal operation of the chip.

[edit] if the circuit was perfectly balanced, the voltage between the two capacitors would be 0. In a real circuit with real components that might not be the case, so there would be currents flowing through that point. That may have caused an EMC issue, so they deleted the track. EMC is a bit of a black art - it is all based on some fundamental physics but due to the number of variables, it is not a simple task to model everything. Each pcb track has inductance, capacitance, resistance as does each wire and component. A small change can cause a significant shift in the EMC performance. Experienced people can look at the spectrum analyzer results and can guestimate what might be causing a peak at a particular frequency.

Comment: I'm marking this as correct. Even though there's something wrong with the premise of my question, you did a good job describing the effects of that ground and purpose of that part of the circuit, which was the other big part of my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add that the missing grounded C connections are much smaller than TI's datasheet, but exist with the close proximity of the aluminum backplate attached to PCB ground for EMI suppression and therefore has an equivalent circuit, if you also used a similar grounded backplate.

If the circuit is balanced by good component and parasitic ESL matching, then that node is 0V and therefore has little current flowing at audio frequencies and only the common mode switching f & harmonics only need a small C to ground plane.

Nice pictures.  Analysis needs Test Experience for parasitic ESL (~8 nH/cm) layout balance and coupling to gnd-plane ~1 pF per mm^2 <1 mm gap.

Please verify my assumptions.

Comment: Oh, neat. This makes complete sense. The output traces are close to ground traces on both sides of the board and IIRC the backplate was [just a few mm from the board](https://i.imgur.com/yThfQTt.png). I did not use a backplate in my setup, though; but I still have most of the chassis from the original TV, and setting up shielding again is probably a good idea anyways.

Comment: One thing I've been wondering about, though, is, what are [these large blobs of solder for](https://i.imgur.com/iHe35wD.jpg)? Are they related to any of this? (If it's involved or they're unrelated; I'll ask a new question about it.)

Comment: These are normally seen in power circuits to decrease the resistance of the track. It might also be to create a number of ‘lumps’ to lessen the possibility of the track resonating. I can’t say I’ve resorted to doing such things myself.

Comment: @Kartman Interesting; thanks. The strips that cut across the large ground trace on the back are directly opposite the output half of the chip, I wonder if that's coincidence or if it has some effect related to capacitance there. Btw, are big blobs like that ever used to physically stabilize the PCB... ? Trying to think about why that set might be where it is, and if that chip puts out a decent amount of heat, maybe they're also there to stiffen up the board -- or just dissipate heat -- so thermal expansion on one side doesn't warp the board / fatigue solder joints? Or does that not happen...

Comment: @JasonC the Blobs are a normal result of solder stencil with paste applied to whole board "screen printed" but parts excluded from the build then reflowed into a blob. no issue.  Faulty Probes are a fart of nature, always calibrate your probes before use with any DC you know exists or square pulse for DSO

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Thanks for your time, much appreciated. Even though those grounds look to be connected (and I won't be able to sleep at night until I figure out how, lol), I still learned a lot here. Happy New Year!

Comment: IF there are more than 2 layers blind vias and blind traces are possible

Comment: Yeah, and that was my first thought. But there's strong evidence that it's only 2 layers: (1) I cut this from the main board with a bandsaw and only saw two layers on that border; (2) I am able to account for *every* connection on the schematic with the visible PCB traces except for this ground (I checked *carefully*, every component, in the amp section as well as the main audio processor and aux amp); (3) the service manual's PCB layouts on page 54 don't show any indications of blind vias/traces; and (4) it would be trivial to route those to the ground trace. So...

Comment: ... given that cost reduction is important, wouldn't it be strange to have another layer just for one or two grounds? Especially ones that could easily be connected on the existing (front) layer? (PS I found the correct service manual; there's no interesting differences. I updated the links in the question though.) Like; maybe it's got another layer, but intuitively that seems like it'd be a super weird choice.... right?

Comment: The cost of EMI CM chokes and plastic filter caps needs to be compared with the cost of copper must be considered for high EMI generation of the class D output.

Comment: Makes sense, or at least, I'm sure whatever they did was for a good reason. Fwiw a [hastily edited video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X3oYKw0u4i0) showing the cross section at the edges (I found some footage from when I cut it). Thanks again. I'm going to keep investigating this and ask a new question if I spot anything weird. ✌

Comment: Good . 2L . I forgot was there a technical problem with sound or EMI or just curiosity. My theory is that the 1uF caps are mismatched worse than the traces and inductance so a floating ground plane becomes a radiator, if caps are gnded,  while an earth ground suppresses it from low impedance.⏱⚙️⚰️ Happy '22

Comment: Haha, thanks. The board: Noise issues -> curiosity. It's unsettlingly sensitive to stray capacitance on the input. I actually think I know what the issue is (it's in the input section; topic for another post). But the first thing I did was retrace all the grounds on the PCB just to make sure I didn't accidentally isolate a portion when I cut the board. That's when I noticed the weird grounds in this question.

PS 

Comment: If you have FG nearby, wire it with a plastic cap to the subplate . Your 100 pF finger has a 100nF body antenna injecting Efield at high CM impedance. A frame ground ,FG cap will shunt that 100 pF easily like 10 to 100 nF  or so. Of course you can also direct connect PE gnd too but so safety in case of some inner fault, a series cap to shunt line E field noise is what you need due to unbalanced source impedance. So add this your your backplate.